# Esp8266 reset infinitely

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I am making this code to control leds by internet  but also I like to add an switch to turn it on and off in case I dont have access to internet. So my problem is that it works normally when I upload the code but when the ESP8266 get restarted the code doesnt work any longer. Every part of the code works fine independently but when I put them together it doesnot work

```
 wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
 wifi.sta.config("BELL", "BLACKST")
 print(wifi.sta.getip())
 led1 = 3
 led2 = 4

 gpio.mode(led2, gpio.OUTPUT)

  srv=net.createServer(net.TCP)
   srv:listen(80,function(conn)
   conn:on("receive", function(client,request)
    local buf = "";
    local _, _, method, path, vars = string.find(request, "([A-Z]+) (.+)?     (.+) HTTP");
    if(method == nil)then
        _, _, method, path = string.find(request, "([A-Z]+) (.+) HTTP");
    end
    local _GET = {}
    if (vars ~= nil)then
        for k, v in string.gmatch(vars, "(%w+)=(%w+)&*") do
            _GET[k] = v
        end
    end


     buf = buf.."<h1> LIGHTS CONTROL </h1>";
     buf = buf.."<p>Aldo's Room <a href=\"?pin=ON1\"><button>ON</button> </a>&nbsp;<a href=\"?pin=OFF1\"><button>OFF</button></a></p>";
      local _on,_off = "",""


    if(_GET.pin == "ON1")then
          gpio.write(led2, gpio.HIGH) ; 

    elseif(_GET.pin == "OFF1")then
          gpio.write(led2, gpio.LOW) ;


    end
    client:send(buf);
    client:close();
    collectgarbage();
     end)
     end)

     gpio.mode(led1, gpio.INT)
    gpio.trig(led1, "both", function(level)

    gpio.write(led2, level)
    end)
```

Comment: Hopefully a silly question, but did you put this in init.lua?

Comment: Also, I recommend using a recent NodeMCU firmware, not 0.9.6. And you might try waiting for the WIFI to be connected, a bit like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288026/the-wifi-sta-module-connects-if-a-loop-is-running/33309872#33309872

Comment: yes I did it, I suspect there is a bug in my init.lua but I can't find it

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to be put into a file called `init.lua`.

http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/upload/#initlua

> You will see "lua: cannot open init.lua" printed to the serial console
>   when the device boots after it's been freshly flashed. If NodeMCU
>   finds a init.lua in the root of the file system it will execute it as
>   part of the boot sequence (standard Lua feature). Hence, your
>   application is initialized and triggered from init.lua. Usually you
>   first set up the WiFi connection and only continue once that has been
>   successful.

With [ESPlorer](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/upload/#esplorer) one way to achieve this would be to store the file locally on your file system as `init.lua` and then hit the 'Save to ESP' button.

Comment: Yeah I save the file as init.lua then I hit to Save to ESP, the first time it works fine but when it is turn off the ESP keeps reseting every time.

Comment: I am suspecting there is a bug in my init.lua but I can't find it

Comment: Yeah I save the file as init.lua then I hit to Save to ESP, the first time it works fine but when it is turn off the ESP keeps reseting every time